# Annihilator of an ideal in an R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

From Dummit Foot, 10.1 ex.11b)

Let M be the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{24Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{15Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{50Z}$. Let $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ and describe the annihilator I in M as a direct product of cyclic groups.

For reference, If I is a right ideal of R, the annihilator of I in M is $\{m\in M| am=0 ~\forall a\in I \}$

Thanks.

Comment: So, that should be "the annihilator *of* $I$ in $M$"?

Comment: So... what is the problem you are having with this?

Comment: P.S. *Please* try to use a tag in *addition* to "abstract algebra". If you are posting a question on group theory, use [group-theory]; here, it is clear [modules] should be a tag.

Comment: Normally we talk about the annihilator of a module (or element of a module) inside of a ring, but this is a well-defined notion as stated.

Comment: @BenjaminLim: The module in quesiton is the abelian group $M$.

Comment: @BenjaminLim: Abelian groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Multiplication by $n\cdot m=m+m+\ldots m$ ($n$ times).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The elements of $2\mathbb{Z}$ are even integers i.e. of the form $2m$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Write an arbitrary $x\in\mathrm{Ann}(I)$ in component form as $(a,b,c)\in M$. Since $2x=0$ implies $(2m)x=0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, it suffices to check that $2$ annihilates $x$ in $M$. This can be written as the following congruence system:

$$2a\equiv0\quad (24)$$
$$2b\equiv 0\quad (15)$$
$$2c\equiv0\quad (50)$$

In order, this implies $12|a$, $15|b$ and $25|c$ - this is elementary number theory.

Answer (score 3):

The annihilator of $I$ in $M$ is $\{(x,0,y)\in M:12|x, 25|y\}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$. Try acting on such an element by an element of $I$ (for example, multiplying each coordinate by 2), and do the same with an element not in the annihilator, and it should become clear how I came up with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you first prove some basic facts about the notion of "the annihilator of an ideal in a module", it becomes a simple computation:
$$\begin{align*} & \mathrm{Ann}_{2\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{24Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{15Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{50Z}) \\
&= \mathrm{Ann}_{2\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{24Z})\times \mathrm{Ann}_{2\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{15Z})\times\mathrm{Ann}_{2\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{50Z}) \\
&= (\{0,12\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{24Z}) \times (\{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{15Z}) \times (\{0,25\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{50Z}) \\
& \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \end{align*}$$

The idea is to look at the above computation, convince yourself each step makes sense, then formalize the theorem used in each step as a precise statement of mathematics and prove it.